# R, ubuntu: months function translates months in Spanish

Tags: r, date, ubuntu

I just started with R in the course I'm following, and what I have done so far is to make a script that loads a file.
I'm running R with a Ubuntu 14.04, using Rstudio 1.0.44, if it is important.

My file (a small bit):

```
Date           Time      GAP ...

2006-12-16   17:24:00   0.37

2006-12-16   17:25:00   0.82

2006-12-16   17:26:00   0.66
```

and so on.

I set the column date as date:

```
DB_hpc$Date <- as.Date(DB_hpc$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

but when I do `month(DB_hpc$Date)` it writes `"Diciembre"`.
The settings of my computer are in English, as well as Rstudio and Ubuntu.
I really need it to put it in English, but I have no idea what I did wrong.
I found that I have to set the environment variable to English, but I could not find in which directory.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What does `Sys.getlocale()`return? (I think your computer "knows" where it is.)

Comment: At the beginning of your script `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")`

Answer (score 3):

The help page for `?Sys.getlocale` says that the environment variable "LANGUAGE" will override the locale settings, so in addition to changing the local settings, you may need to investigate that aspect of the internationalization settings on your machine. Examine these results:

```
Sys.getlocale()

names(s <- Sys.getenv())   # More complete listing
s[grep("^L(C|ANG)", names(s))]
```

And then use the corresponding setter functions: `Sys.setlocale` and `Sys.setenv` to fix your problem. To see all the environment variables do this:

```
?"environment variables"
```

I suspect you want to check the accuracy of the suggestion to set the locale to "English". It doesn't match my settings. I would have advised:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")  # or the GB equivalent
```